# Insert value of attribute before each element in the set of elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to use jquery to convert

```
<div data-expand-label="foo" />
<div data-expand-label="bar" />
```

into

```
<p>foo</p>
<div data-expand-label="foo" />
<p>bar</p>
<div data-expand-label="bar" />
```

This is what I thought would work:

```
$('[data-expand-label]').before('<p>'+$(this).attr('[data-expand-label]')+'</p>');
```

but 'this' doesn't seem to work. Why? and what should I do instead?

Comment: You perform no iteration visible to `this`. What's the value you expect it to take?

Comment: 'foo' or 'bar' respctively

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work"

Comment: `this` is only evaluated once. It can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is only evaluated once (per entering the code in question), so it can't be both `<div...foo>` and `<div...bar>`. You will need to iterate over the elements.

`.before` accepts a callback argument, which will happily iterate for you. You do, however, need to supply a callback. Change:

```
$('[data-expand-label]').before(
  '<p>'+$(this).attr('[data-expand-label]')+'</p>'
);
```

(your code) to:

```
$('[data-expand-label]').before(function(){
  return '<p>'+$(this).attr('[data-expand-label]')+'</p>'
});
```

or, better yet, if `data-expand-label` is supposed to be a text,

```
$('[data-expand-label]').before(function(){
  return $('<p>').text($(this).attr('[data-expand-label]'))
});
```

Comment: This executes twice when I run it..?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren the callback is executed once for every element `before` acts upon, just like for `each`

Comment: it was due to too executions of the js-file, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier to try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-expand-label]').each(function() { $(this).before('<p>'+$(this).attr('data-expand-label')+'</p>'); });
});
```

I don't believe you can use "$(this)" in the context in which you were, it needs to be referenced in the above manner.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: When I do this it creates two p-tags?

Comment: Oh, you only want 1 p tag? try creating the p-tag beforehand and then appending the messages to that p-tag, so: $('.p-tag-class').append($(this).attr('data-expand-label'));

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each element you want to apply the new element to, like so:

```
$('div[data-expand-label]').each(function() {
    $(this).before($('<p></p>').html($(this).attr('data-expand-label')));
});
```

Comment: When I do this it creates two p-tags?